# Why was my answer to my own question deleted (The system itself suggested I could answer my own question in Q&A style)?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I had a question on mind, then was able to lookup few links (googling) and post them as answer along with the question. The summary of the question has at least one useful approach. The answer had few additional link references. Does addition of links to external websites qualify as promoting them?

Any how here is the post - [image]

The embedded links are as noted below.

1. [Detecting Cache Misses and Hits Pragmatically in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359524/detecting-cache-misses-and-hits-pragmatically-in-linux)
2. https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/developer_guide/perf
3. https://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html
4. https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2014/03/10/determining-whether-an-application-has-poor-cache-performance-2#
5. [Why doesn't perf report cache misses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674463/why-doesnt-perf-report-cache-misses)
6. https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial
7. [is there a windows equivalent of the linux command "perf stat"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34641644/is-there-a-windows-equivalent-of-the-linux-command-perf-stat)
8. https://github.com/opcm/pcm

The link to answer is here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68339254/2862341

And the link to the question is this -
[How to determine processor cache misses for Java program on Windows and Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68339253/2862341)

Comment: Probably because it seems to be asking more questions. Leave all that out and just provide the answer/explanation. You can leave a comment on the answer to "request clarification"

Comment: I can't since comments are disabled. PS: Added the link to answer.

Comment: Right, i meant out of the gate. Since it's deleted by a mod, you can't do anything further unless they reverse it.

Comment: Looking at the question itself, it is not reasonably scoped "_What approach would I take for the above scenario? For Linux? For Windows? Programmatic ? 3rd Party Utiltiy? System Inbuilt feature?_" This would give rise to multiple answers focusing on one or the other part. i.e. your question lacks focus.

Comment: The above list you mention is for the answers. The question itself only has one scope - jvm and on windows and linux platforms (while its not mentioned in question, it is indicated in the tags).

Comment: The point of the question being focused is so that *answers* don't have to cover such a myriad of topics. "jvm and on windows and linux platforms" is focused in that you can write it down in one sentence, but it is not focused in what kind of answers it invites.

Comment: Not sure what the question is but from reading the answer in the image I would say you can just delete the massive link diarrhea and stick with just the last paragraph/sentence, and state to use Perf for Linux and PCM for Windows. A mountain of links that just say "here" over and over again aren't particularly useful. Oh, and don't use code tagging for tool names like Perf or PCM. It would be appropriate to tag them as code only if you are talking about the actual *command* (which happens to also be "perf" for Linux... not sure about PCM).

Comment: In addition, links rot. so if a question or answer leans to heavily on the information at the linked page, it will become "Not Useful" at some point. All important information must be in the question or answer to preserve it for posterity. If the link is vital and too long to be adapted (or would raise legal/licensing issues), summarize the content so that future readers can recreate the lost information with their own web-searching and possibly update the links if they can find the new home of the linked page.

Comment: @RavindraHV Another tip for the future: Often, if you scope your question's text around the specific problem that you're trying to solve instead of what sorts or answers you're looking for, you'll leave the door open to many types of answers, including those that can come from any of the options you've listed (Linux, Windows, Programmatic solutions, 3rd party utilities, etc.). People with useful solutions will offer them– it's way more important to scope your question well than it is to spread your net super wide.

Comment: Yes; The multiple unquoted links are a problem; You also asked at least two questions, it’s not clear if you want those questions literally answered, but nobody can answer them since they are contained within an answer instead of a question. If those links are to other answers that suggests the question is a duplicate and should be flagged and not actually answered.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There were multiple problems with this answer. You need to read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to learn more about writing good answers.

1. What is `PS:` at the start of the post? Is this meant to be `P.S.` i.e. Post Scriptum? If so, then why is it at the very beginning of the answer?
2. If the same question has been asked before why not post this answer there and then close this question as a duplicate?
3. All answers on Stack Overflow must stand on their own. Any links should be just supplementary and should not constitute the core of the answer. `here` is not the right description for the link. What is this "here" linking to?
4. Asking rhetorical questions in an answer usually is confusing. Are you asking someone to reply to it? Try avoiding rhetorical questions.
5. Why does your solution end with a question? It's an answer, there should be no questions. You are literally offering a solution.

Because the answer is written the way it is, a moderator must have decided that it is of too low quality to remain visible. If you want it to be useful, listen to my advice above and edit the post. You can then flag it to ask for undeletion.

Comment: "*Are you asking someone to reply to it?*" no, I think the rhetorical question is there as a device to showcase something. Oh...

Comment: I have edited the question if its still not clear, will be happy to convert it into a blog post (given that closed posts would be deleted sooner or later). Google searching still takes time and having a question that acts as a book-mark is not all that bad - for those who want answers. That's what I'd thought of initially until I saw the Q&A format. If it were so confusing, it wouldn't have had any answers to it to begin with. Thanks for replying in any case !

Comment: @RavindraHV I edited the question, but I don't think it's reopenable yet. It still sounds like you are asking for opinions rather than fact-based answers. I'm not a Java expert though, so maybe it can be answered with facts...

Comment: Saw it! Thank you for your feedback, in any case!